# Is there a way to make SUBMIT button available only with specific code in the inputs using just HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the SUBMIT button available only when in the three input boxes the person writes the numbers 0 4 2 - in that exact same order.

I know it's easily achievable with JS, but I was wondering if it's possible with only HTML too.

Here's an example link: https://scontent.fskp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/122988049_648515422431558_1560231741132468095_n.png?_nc_cat=109&ccb=2&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=lPPHXpw9wZkAX8pk002&_nc_ht=scontent.fskp1-1.fna&oh=05c12b348cca4c9546d465f41f074603&oe=5FBF87D0

```html
<form action="#">
        <input class="code" type="text" required="required">
        <input class="code" type="text" required="required">
        <input class="code" type="text" required="required"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Unlock" />
</form>
```

Comment: No, you'll need JS to validate the correct input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this works, it's a stupid CSS trick, doesn't have much flexibility, and really shouldn't be used in production.

```css
input[type=submit] {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: red;
}
input:valid + input:valid + input:valid + br + input[type=submit] {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <input class="code" type="text" required="required" pattern="0">
    <input class="code" type="text" required="required" pattern="4">
    <input class="code" type="text" required="required" pattern="2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Unlock" />
</form>
```

The [`:valid` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) matches validated inputs and [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) matches adjacent siblings. [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) prevents clicking.

The [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) attribute sets up a regex to validate a field.

Comment: Impressive! Bravo 

Comment: Genius! Thank you!